# How can Ordering provide implicit Ordering[T] with type erasure in JVM - Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, type-erasure

In scala, to make a class comparable we extends `Ordered[T]` on the class

```
case class A(i: Int) extends Ordered[A] {
  def compare(that: A): Int = this.i compare that.i 
}
```

and `Iteratable[A]`'s method `sorted` requires implicit parameter of type `scala.math.Ordering[A]` to sort `Iterable[A]`

```
Seq[A](A(2),A(1)).sorted // Seq(A(1),A(2)) Ordering will provide Ordering[A]
Seq[A](A(2),A(1)).sorted(Ordering[A]) // Seq(A(1),A(2))
```

and the `Ordering` companion object provides an implicit `Ordering[T]` for `Iterable[A]`

My question: How can the `Ordering` object can provide `Ordering[T]` to `sorted`.

Since `[T]` will be removed by JVM and it is impossible to know difference between

`Ordering[A]` and `Ordering[Int]`

How come it can work??

Answer (score 4):

> How come it can work?

Implicits are a *compile time* feature. That is, when you compile your code, the compiler enforces rules which need to check out. In this particular case, an implicit of type `Ordering[Int]` needs to be available in scope, otherwise you'll get a compilation error.

This means that at run-time, even though the types are *erased*, you can guarantee that there will be an `Ordering[Int]` available, even though it will look like an `Ordering(obj: Object)`, you've already fulfilled the guarantee of it being able to order the underlying `Int` objects which otherwise wouldn't allow your code to compile.